# IDAPython dump hex pres of opcode to file

Tags: python, hex, ida, opcode

I try to dump the hex presentation of opcode next to the opcode into a text file but I was not really successful yet. This is how it looks like now:

```
.init_proc   start: 6a0  end: 6b0
6a0  å-à   PUSH  {LR}; _init
6a4  ëO    BL    frame_dummy
6a8  ë¨    BL    __do_global_ctors_aux
6ac  äð    POP   {PC}

strerror     start: 6c4  end: 6d0
6c4  âÆ    ADR   R12, 0x6CC
6c8  âŒÊ   ADD   R12, R12, #0x8000
6cc  å¼þ`  LDR   PC, [R12,#(strerror_ptr - 0x86CC)]!; __imp_strerror
```

Unfortunately, the get_bytes function only returns a string and not an integer, so
I cannot convert it into hex. Is there any other way to do this?
This is my idapython script:

```
cur_addr = 0

with open("F:/Ida_scripts/ida_output.txt", "w") as f:
    for func in Functions():
        start = get_func_attr(func, FUNCATTR_START)
        end = get_func_attr(func, FUNCATTR_END)
        f.write("%s\t start: %x\t end: %x" % (get_func_name(func), start, end))
        cur_addr = start
        while cur_addr <= end:
            f.write("\n%x\t%s\t%s" % (curr_addr, get_bytes(cur_addr, get_item_size(curr_addr)), generate_disasm_line(cur_addr, 0)))
            cur_addr = next_head(cur_addr, end)
        f.write("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `get_bytes()` returns a string, then I assume you want to convert every byte in this string to hex and print that instead.  Try this:

```
print(' '.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in get_bytes(…))
```

This will print something like this:

```
61 62 63 64
```

(For `'abcd'` as input.)

Or as a function:

```
def str_to_hex(s):
  return ' '.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in s)
```

Notice that in Python3 the `str` type is a unicode datatype, so it will be more than just a byte per character; there you have the `bytes` type for byte arrays (maybe your `get_bytes()` should return this instead of a string then).  In Python2 the `str` type is a byte array and the `unicode` type is for unicode strings.  I don't know in which Python version you are developing.

Comment: Thanks a million! This is exactly what I needed. Unfortunately the get_bytes() function is part of IDA's idc library.